# GCE: Ubuntu 18.04 custom image has no connectivity/SSH?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04, vmware-workstation

I'm currently struggling to get a custom image of Ubuntu 18.04LTS to work in GCE. I'm using the Ubuntu Desktop version, since installing gdm3 afterwards on Google stock Ubuntu just doesn't seem to deliver the experience my users need (I'll be using NoMachine to make the users use the instance).

The instance seems to build successfully. However, I can't seem to ping the instance to it's internal/ephemeral IP, and SSH won't work either.
This image is made using VMWare Workstation 12, which means I'm uploading the single .VMDK file from the VM to GCP to form an image. The image builds with success, no errors included. Ofcourse, everything works fine when I work the VM in VMware.

- I ran the Google Cloud Precheck tool in the VM; passes without a doubt.
- I followed Google's [guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/configuring-imported-images) to configure SSH, DHCP, NTP etc. Services are all enabled, running and accessable from my PC when used in VMware.
- VM's firewall is disabled, GCE's firewall is open.
- Guest packages are included while creating the image.

[Further research](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/building-custom-os) makes me think the VM needs additional KVM/VirtIO/Kernel packages or configuration, although I'm not completely sure where to start or if it will fix anything. I'm basically completely clueless why the thing won't work since it doesn't seems to have the least of connectivity.

This is part of the serial-output when deploying the instance from the custom image, after trying to SSH into it. This output seems to loop endlessly. Anyone who can help me? What steps did I miss here?

````
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice user-121.slice.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 121...

         Starting User Manager for UID 121...

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[1]: Started Session c502 of user gdm.

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Session c502 of user gdm.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).

May 20 13:31:13 inrun-user-121.mount
st-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Reached target Timers.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Started Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Reached target Paths.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Listening on Sound System.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Reached target Sockets.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Reached target Basic System.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 121.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Reached target Default.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Startup finished in 34ms.

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started User Manager for UID 121.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d dbus-daemon[15452]: [session uid=121 pid=15452] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d gnome-session-binary[15454]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1

         Stopping User Manager for UID 121...

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 121...

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Stopped target Default.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Stopped target Basic System.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Stopped target Paths.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Stopped Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Stopped target Sockets.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access foruser@121.service
 web browsers).

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Closed Sound System.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Stopped target Timers.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Reached target Shutdown.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Starting Exit the Session...

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[15438]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 15471 (kill).

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped User Manager for UID 121.

[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Removed slice user-121.slice.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 121.

May 20 13:31:13 inst-translator-import-and-translate-translate-translate-qw66d systemd[1]: Removed slice user-121.slice.```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try consulting this doc https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh, if that doesn't work, I'd suggest opening either a support case or an issue tracker https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers with GCP support so they can dive into your project to look further.